# What is this anime where a poor girl forced is to wash an ugly guest that's very muddy?

Tags: spirited-away

I remember a scene from an anime which I can't identify. (I don't remember whether it was a film or a series.) It was in the style of *The Girl Who Leapt Through Time*. I watched it about 3-10 years ago but it could be much older.

What I remember: A poor girl works in a public bath and is forced to wash a special guest who the other girls working there don't want to wash. The guest is coated in mud. The girl gets help (maybe animals?) / a special soap. She uses the soap on the customer and the mud vanishes. As a thank-you she gets a reward. I think I could see gold coins in this scene.

I already went through the list of anime I remember watching but it was none of them. As this scene regularly comes to my mind, it annoys me not to know where it's from.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is presumably the scene from *Spirited Away* where Sen has to clean the river spirit. ([here's a crappy camrip on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bnjTr1Bfm0))

Comment: wow, you are right
I wonder, why it wasn't on my list and I searched weeks for it.
Maybe because I searched in English and the title in English is completly different

Comment: @sweethome Nope, still the same title in English. Very good film by the way, Studio Ghibli's best :)

Comment: Or in Japanese: 千と千尋の神隠し Interestingly, the scene you refer to was based on the director's own experience of cleaning a river :)

Comment: The literal translation of the title I know would be "Chihiros travel into the land of magic", so I would have never expected this English title since I didn't know that meaning of "to spirit so./sth. away" (English is not my mother language). Yes, Ghibli produces nice adventure movies for the whole family. That's also the reason why they show them sometimes on our local kids TV chanel (other anime movies aren't even shown on German TV stations). That's most probably is also where I saw it and I think, I will give it a rewatch tomorrow :)

Comment: @sweethome The German title is actually closer to the original Japanese, which translates as "The spiriting-away of Chihiro and Sen". I don't know why the English title is so different; presumably some marketer decided that a shorter/punchier title would sell better with English-speaking audiences.

Comment: @senshin yes, that's what I ment and as I didn't know the term "to spirit away", I would never have guessed that this was the English title of this movie but I noticed with many movies/... that the English title was less descriptive than in other languages. When I now hear the English title I will know which one it is ;)